# javascript, add function to prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, currying

In javascript, is possible add functions to a prototype with something similar to a curry?

I try with this code

```
var helloGoodBye = function (name, fun) {
  return function(message) {
    console.log('hello : ' + name);
    console.log(message);
    console.log('byebye : ' + name);
    return fun(message)
  }                                                                                           
}

var Machine = function (){
  this.state = 'green';
};

Machine.prototype = {
  green: helloGoodBye('green', function (message){
    this.state = 'red';
  }),
  red: helloGoodBye('red', function (message){
    this.state = 'green';
  })
}

var sm = new Machine();

sm[sm.state]('first message');
sm[sm.state]('second message');
```

and I get this output

```
"hello state: green"
"first message"
"byebye state: green"
"hello state: green"
"second message"
"byebye state: green"
```

but this way don't work, maybe because the `this.state` called in the functions is a `this.state` living in the global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to make the method invoke the `fun` callback on the receiver object. Use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
function helloGoodBye(name, fun) {
  return function(message) {
    console.log('hello : ' + name);
    console.log(message);
    console.log('byebye : ' + name);
    return fun.call(this, message);
//            ^^^^^ ^^^^
  }                                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this` inside `func` is not the instance of your class. It's the global object `window`. The anonymous function returned by `helloGoodBye` is the one that has its `this` set to the instance of the class (it is the function attached to the prototype). `func` is an anonymous function trapped in the closure, but it has nothing to do with the instance of the class itself.

Use an alternative to such as `Function.prototype.call` to explicitly specify the `this`:

```js
var helloGoodBye = function (name, fun) {
  return function(message) {
    console.log('hello : ' + name);
    console.log(message);
    console.log('byebye : ' + name);
    return fun.call(this, message); // use the this in this scope which will be the instance of the object
  }                                                                                           
}

var Machine = function (){
  this.state = 'green';
};

Machine.prototype = {
  green: helloGoodBye('green', function(message) {
    this.state = 'red';
  }),
  red: helloGoodBye('red', function(message) {
    this.state = 'green';
  })
}

var sm = new Machine();

console.log(sm);
sm[sm.state]('first message');
sm[sm.state]('second message');
```